# Android-Application within an another application

Tags: android

I get want to know how to deploy a application within a another application in android.for example mms application is get deployed within the message application and QuickSearchbox within contacts.how to do this one.There is now separate icon in launcher for QuickSearchBox or mms application.How to do it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "for example mms application is get deployed within the message application" -- there is no "mms application". "and QuickSearchbox within contacts" -- the Quick Search Box is part of the operating system, not part of an application.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean search Dialog then please refer 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html
to use search dialog.